# Hyper-V Network Adapter

Tags: internet, virtualization, windows-server-2008, network-adapter, hyper-v

I have a setup a Hyper-V VM on my server. I have the NIC setup in Hyper-V manager. I also have the my VM settings pointing to my NIC. I can't access the Internet. Here is a picture of my Hyper-V settings:

[image: Hyper-V Network Settings]

You might notice that in the screen shot nothing is showing up under my MAC Address. That is because I cropped it out of the picture.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not sure if this is of any relevance, but I am also unable to install the integration services disk at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS was Windows XP Pro. I had to add a Legacy Network Adapter the the hardware of my VM, and disable the other one. Once I did that the VM recognized the new hardware, and I could obtain an IP Address.